# Blank in RLS means visible or not visible?

Tags: dax, ssas, cube, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

I have this legacy cube, in roles I see the ReadAll_Admin role, where we have full access to the data:

Screenshot:
[image]

I have a few questions:

- It says “Only rows that match the specified filters are visible to users in this role”, what if it remains blank like above?! What’s the default “visible” or “not visible”?!
- I tested the role above and I can read all data, how is it possible?
- What could be a reasonable case as the above: that is, where you leave all tables blank, and =FALSE() in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Only rows that match the specified filters are visible to users in
   this role”, what if it remains blank like above?! What’s the default
   “visible” or “not visible”?

   ```
   Default is 'Visible'
   ```
2. I tested the role above and I can read all data, how is it possible?

   ```
   You should be able to read all data except dimension with FALSE() filter
   ```
3. What could be a reasonable case as the
   above: that is, where you leave all tables blank, and =FALSE() in
   one?

   ```
   This table might contain USERNAME or other information which should not be visible to users
   ```